# Interface with generic parameters- can't get it to compile

Tags: java, generics, interface

I have an interface like so:

```
public interface MyInterface<E extends Something1> {
    public void meth1(MyClass1<E> x);
}
```

and I have a subclass whose superclass implements the above interface:

```
public class MyClass2<E extends Something1> extends Superclass{

    public MyClass2(){

    }

    public void meth1(MyClass1 x) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

superclass:

```
public abstract class Superclass<E extends Something1> implements MyInterface{
    MyClass1<E> x;
    protected E y;

    public Superclass(){

    }
}
```

MyClass1:

```
public abstract class Myclass1<E extends Something1> {

    public Myclass1(){

    }
}
```

the problem is that the parameter for meth1() is supposed to be generic. If I do MyClass1 it doesn't like it and the only way I can get it to compile is by leaving out generic parameters- which feels wrong.

What's going wrong?

Comment: Pls post the code for MyClass1

Comment: @munyengm i have now included it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are your classes now parameterised appropriately:

```
class Something1 { }

public interface MyInterface<E extends Something1> {
    public void meth1(MyClass1<E> x);
}

// and I have a subclass whose superclass implements the above interface:
public class MyClass2<E extends Something1>
    extends Superclass<E> {

    public MyClass2() { }

    public void meth1(MyClass1<E> x) { }
}

// superclass:
public abstract class Superclass<E extends Something1> implements
        MyInterface<E> {
    MyClass1<E> x;
    protected E y;

    public Superclass() { }
}

// MyClass1:
public abstract class MyClass1<E extends Something1> {

    public MyClass1() {

    }
}
```

Comment: @SergiiZagriichuk No - in case you weren't aware the controversy with software patents is precisely due to the fact that two different people working on the same problem can come up with the same solution. I just took the OP's code, pasted into my compiler and resolved the errors - simples :-)

Answer (score 1):

So, this compiles, where MyClass1 happens to be a List:
Did I miss something? Is your code different? If it's all the same, there might be something going on with your choice of MyClass1. Also, we're missing the superclass of MyClass2, which could also be problematic...

```
import java.util.List;

public class MyClass2<E extends Object> extends Object{

    public MyClass2(){

    }

    public void meth1(List<E> x) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}

interface MyInterface<E extends Object> {
    public void meth1(List<E> x);
}
```

Comment: I have now edited to include the superclass above. I am going to guess the abstract makes a difference?

Answer (score 1):

Not mandatory

```
public abstract class Superclass<E extends Something1> implements MyInterface<E>
```

Mandatory

```
public class MyClass2<E extends Something1> extends Superclass<E>
```

All will compile and method will be generic

Comment: Hi, could you elaborate on why this is?

Comment: By Default generic value is Object, and you did not add any points about generic into implementation of class MyClass2, So, Compiler will add Myclass1 with generic value as Object and that is all